# Laravel create a 1-1 relationship from a many-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Hi I'm having a struggle trying to return a single record from a many to many relationship.

So in my app I've Clubs and Addresses entities.

Clubs have 0, 1 or n Addresses and one of them may be the main address.

An Address can also be used by some other entities (like Events, Members etc..)

My tables are the following :

- `clubs: id, name`
- `addresses: id, street, city, zip club`
- `club_address: id, club_id, address_id, is_main`

I can currently request all the addresses of my club like so :

```
class Club {
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Address', 'club_address', 'club_id', 'address_id')->withPivot('is_main'); // club_address
    }
}
```

Now what I'd like is to get the main address or null when I request a club.

I can't be satisfied with simply adding ->wherePivot('is_main', '=', 1) because it's still returning an array of 1 or 0 element when I want an array or null.

I'd like something like this

```
class Club {
    // Get all the addresses in an array
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Address', 'club_address', 'club_id', 'address_id')->withPivot('is_main'); // club_address
    }

    // Get the main address or null
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->addresses()->wherePivot('is_main', '=', 1)->first();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I can't eager load `address` because it's not returning a Relation Model ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do the trick by extending the BelongsToMany Relation class and overriding two methods with their BelongsTo Relation equivalent.

But I wouldn't say it's prudent to use this, but it seems ok for my uses.

```
namespace App\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class BelongsToOneFromMany extends BelongsToMany {

    /**
     * Initialize the relation on a set of models.
     *
     * @param  array   $models
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return array
     */
    public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
    {
        foreach ($models as $model)
        {
            $model->setRelation($relation, null);
        }

        return $models;
    }

    /**
     * Match the eagerly loaded results to their parents.
     *
     * @param  array   $models
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $results
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return array
     */
    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {
        $foreign = $this->foreignKey;

        $other = $this->otherKey;

        // First we will get to build a dictionary of the child models by their primary
        // key of the relationship, then we can easily match the children back onto
        // the parents using that dictionary and the primary key of the children.
        $dictionary = array();

        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
            $dictionary[$result->getAttribute($other)] = $result;
        }

        // Once we have the dictionary constructed, we can loop through all the parents
        // and match back onto their children using these keys of the dictionary and
        // the primary key of the children to map them onto the correct instances.
        foreach ($models as $model)
        {
            if (isset($dictionary[$model->$foreign]))
            {
                $model->setRelation($relation, $dictionary[$model->$foreign]);
            }
        }

        return $models;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`first()` on an eloquent model returns a collection - even if that collection is zero (which is what you have basically said).

However `first()` on a collection returns `null` is there is no first...

So..

```
class Club {
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Address', 'club_address', 'club_id', 'address_id')->withPivot('is_main');
    }

    public function address()
    {
        // First first is on the model, second first 
        // is on the collection
        return $this->addresses()
            ->wherePivot('is_main', '=', 1)
            ->first()
            ->first(); 
    }
}
```

**Note** This is essentially just a shorthand trick. Your attribute could just as easily, and possibly more readable, use something like:

```
class Club {
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Address', 'club_address', 'club_id', 'address_id')->withPivot('is_main');
    }

    public function address()
    {
        $record = $this->addresses()
            ->wherePivot('is_main', '=', 1)
            ->first();

        return count($record) === 0 ? null : $record;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about `first()` on a collection thanks :)

But I still can't use that as a relationship. In the end I'd like to use this relationship with eager loading, as such `Club::with('address')->get();`.